# Exclude terminator when writing to file

Tags: c

I'm receiving a message through a socket in C which is written to a buffer. The message has a terminator (`@@`) added to the end so I know when to stop writing to the buffer, however, the buffer is much larger than the message. Is there a way to write only up to and not including the terminator, throwing away the rest of the buffer?

Maybe something with a position pointer?

```
char *pos;
FILE* fp = fopen("tempfile", "w+");
pos = strstr(buffer, "@@");
pos = '\0';    // Maybe I could stop the writing with NULL?

fwrite(buffer, 1, BUF_SIZE /*too big*/, fp);
fclose(fp);
```

I need to get the size of the portion of the buffer that contains the message, or maybe only write to my file up to a certain character. Either way would work.

Comment: `fwrite(buffer, 1, pos-buffer, fp)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Statement `fwrite(buffer, 1, BUF_SIZE, fp)` will write `BUF_SIZE` bytes, regardless of the actual content of the buffer and regardless if it contains a `'\0'` considered as "string termination".
So the only way is to tell `fwrite` the correct number of elements to write; and this can be easily calculated through pointer arithmetics:

```
fwrite(buffer, 1, pos-buffer, fp)
```

Of course, you'll have to check if `pos != NULL` and so on; but I think this is straight forward.